# nginx - php7.0-fpm php scripts no works with alias

Tags: nginx, php-7

i want to create routing like a:

- hxxp://127.0.0.1/ <-- default with default location /var/www/ without listning directories
- hxxp://127.0.0.1/allegro/

How to do it? 
If i go to hxxp://127.0.0.1/allegro/scripts/test.php i see a blank page. If i go to hxxp://127.0.0.1/ php scripts excutes normally and i see phpinfo()

My nginx config:

```
server {
listen 8000 default_server;
listen [::]:8000 default_server;

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name localhost;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location /allegro/ {
    alias /var/www/allegro/;
    autoindex on;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try `root /var/www;` instead of `alias /var/www/allegro/;` (inside the `location /allegro/` block)

Comment: Still blank page on 127.0.0.1/allegro/script/test.php :(

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your current configuration. The most important is that the URI `/allegro/scripts/test.php` is **not** processed by the nested location block, because regular expression location blocks take precedence (unless a `^~` modifier is used).

```
location ^~ /allegro/ {
    root /var/www;
#   autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The `^~` modifier ensures that this *prefix location* takes precedence over *regular expression locations* at the same level. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Note that the `root` statement is preferred over an `alias` statement where applicable (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details).

The `fastcgi_split_path_info` and `fastcgi_index` directives are unnecessary for location blocks which do not match URIs with path info.

You will need to decide whether `include fastcgi_params` or `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` is the more appropriate source for FastCGI parameters.

Comment: Still blank page :/